# Password Change in Php, Php is returning blank

Tags: php, passwords, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a password change page for a website I am attempting to make. However when the user enters in the information to the form it sends me to a blank page. In other words my php code is not even executing and I am not sure why. I have tried it a few different ways but I am not entirely sure whats going on. This is my first time making a settings page or website in general so maybe its a simple mistake or I'm going about it all wrong. Here is my php code.

```
 <!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $db_server = "server";
        $db_username = "name";
        $db_password = "pass";

        $con = mysql_connect($db_server, $db_username, $db_password);
        if (!$con) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $database = "Account_Holder";

        $er = mysql_select_db($db_username);
        if (!$er) {
            print ("Error - Could not select the database");
            exit;
        }
        $username = $_P0ST['username'];
        $cur_password = $_POST['cur_password'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $password2 = $_POST['password2'];

        // Check for an existing password.
        if (isset($_POST['cur_password'])) 
            {
            $pass = FALSE;
            print('<p>You forgot to enter your existing password!</p>');
        }
        else {
            $pass = escape_data($_POST['cur_password']);
        }
        // Check for a password and match against the confirmed password.
        if (empty($_POST['password'])) 
            {
            $newpass = FALSE;
            print('<p>You forgot to enter your new password!</p>');
            } 
        else 
            {
            if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['password2']) {
                $newpass = escape_data($_POST['password']);
            } 
            else
                {
                $newpass = FALSE;
                $message .= '<p>Your new password did not match the confirmed new password!</p>';
                }


        if ($pass && $newpass) { // If checking passes 
            $query = "SELECT * FROM Account_Holder WHERE password='$pass')";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if ($num == 1) {
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

// Make the query.
                $query = ("UPDATE Account_Holder SET password='$newpass' WHERE username=$username");
                $result = mysql_query($query); // Run the query.
                if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) { // If it ran OK.

                    echo '<p><b>Your password has been changed.</b></p>';
                } 

                else 
                 { // If query failed.

                    print('<p>Your password was not changed.</p><p>' . mysql_error() . '</p>');
                }
            } else
                {
                print('<p>Your username and password did not match any in the database.</p>');
                }
        }
            else 
                {
                print('<p>Please try again.</p>');
            }
            }


        ?> 

    </body>
</html>











   <!--
 I also did it this way and all the validations work and it says the password was updated but it does not change in the database. Is something wrong with my sql?
    -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Change Password Confrim</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
      $db_server = "server";
       $db_username = "name";
       $db_password = "pass";

       $con = mysql_connect($db_server, $db_username, $db_password);if (!$con)
                {
                    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }

               $database = "Account_Holder";  

              $er = mysql_select_db($db_username);
        if (!$er) 
        {
         print ("Error - Could not select the database");
         exit;
        }        


//include "include/session.php";
// check the login details of the user and stop execution if not logged in
//require "check.php";
//////////Collect the form data ////////////////////
$username =$_P0ST['username'];
$todo=$_POST['todo'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$password2=$_POST['password2'];
/////////////////////////

if(isset($todo) and $todo=="change-password"){
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
$password2 = mysql_real_escape_string($password2);

//Setting flags for checking
$status = "OK";
$msg="";

//Checking to see if password is at least 3 char max 8 
if ( strlen($password) < 3 or strlen($password) > 8 )
{
    $msg=$msg."Password must be more than 3 char legth and maximum 8 char lenght<br/>";
    $status= "NOTOK";
}                   

//Checking to see if both passwords match 
if ( $password <> $password2 )
{
    $msg=$msg."Both passwords are not matching<br/>";
    $status= "NOTOK";
}                   

if($status<>"OK")
{ 
    echo "<font face='Verdana' size='2' color=red>$msg</font><br><center><input type='button' value='Retry' onClick='history.go(-1)'></center>";
}
else
{ // if all validations are passed.
    if(mysql_query("UPDATE Account_Holder SET password='$password' WHERE username='$username'"))
    {
        echo "<font face='Verdana' size='2' ><center>Thanks <br> Your password changed successfully.</font></center>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<font face='Verdana' size='2' color=red><center>Sorry <br> Failed to change password.</font></center>";
    }
}
}
//require "bottom.php";

?>
<center>
<br><br><a href='Settings.html'>Settings Page</a></center> 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you might wanted to check out your e.g apache log , php may complain for errors there

Comment: Did you catch the 0 in $_POST['username']?

Comment: As @MorganDelaney points out, there's a zero where there should be an O `$username = $_P0ST['username'];`

Comment: Or the database being selected is the database username and not the database variable?

Answer (score 3):

I wish I could just leave a comment. But no.
You have a lot of errors in your code such as this

```
$username = $_P0ST['username'];
```

Im guessing error reporting is turned off on the page, so you don't see the syntax errors, and you just get a blank page.

Turn on errors. This may work.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

A few comments:

```
    $er = mysql_select_db($db_username);
```

This is the wrong variable.

```
    $username = $_P0ST['username'];
```

A zero instead of a letter O.

```
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Account_Holder WHERE password='$pass')";
```

and

```
            $query = ("UPDATE Account_Holder SET password='$newpass' WHERE username=$username");
```

Can you say "SQL injection"? Also, missing quotes around the username value.

As mentioned by `Adam Meyer` above, you appear to have error reporting off. Either that, or you have output buffering somewhere and yet another syntax error in there.